# Find the points where the following function is differentiable:

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\arctan {x},  & \text{if $|x| \leq 1$} \\[2ex]
\dfrac{\pi x}{4 |x|} + \dfrac{|x|-1}{2}& \text{if $|x| > 1$}
\end{cases}
$$
I think the function is continuous only where the values coincide. But, don't know about differentiability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuity is a problem only at $1$ and $-1$. However,
$$
\lim_{x\to1^+}f(x)=
\lim_{x\to 1^+}\left(\frac{\pi x}{4x}+\frac{x-1}{2}\right)=\frac{\pi}{4}
$$
and the same for the limit $x\to 1^-$. Similarly at $-1$.

For $0<x<1$ we have
$$
f'(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}
$$
whereas, for $x>1$,
$$
f'(x)=\frac{1}{2}
$$
Therefore
$$
\lim_{x\to1}f'(x)=\frac{1}{2}
$$
Apply l‘Hôpital.

What happens at $-1$?

Comment: I can't understand why continuity is a problem at 1 and -1

Comment: @Infinity It's where the definition “changes”. Any other point has a neighborhood where the function is (the restriction of) a continuous function.